# Jest v22.0.6 always convert process.env array toString

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, tostring, jestjs

I'm currently using yarn 1.3.2 and trying to migrate from jest 22.0.5 to latest version, but I did find a problem from v22.0.6

This is our very simple `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    setupFiles: ['./tools/test/setup.js']
}
```

And this is a simpler `setup.js` we use to debug this problem

```
const array = ['en', 'fr']
process.env.ARRAY = array
console.log('process.env.ARRAY', process.env.ARRAY)
```

In one of our test, we loop an `process.env` array and this is our output

22.0.5

```
console.log tools/test/setup.js:3
    process.env.ARRAY ['en', 'fr']
```

22.0.6

```
console.log tools/test/setup.js:3
    process.env.ARRAY en,fr
```

It seems that every process.env array to be converted with `toString()`

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to Jest, it's just the way `process.env` works in Node.js.

To quote from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env):

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string.

So when you assign an array `['en', 'fr']` to `process.env.ARRAY`, it is converted to the string `en,fr`.

If you need to convert this string back to an array somewhere else in your code, you could use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
const array = process.env.ARRAY.split(',');
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am sure I get this problem only with that version of jest. No problem with earlier version or inside the application.